# Understanding $\int_0^{2\pi} da e ^{p \cos a}= 2\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(p/2)^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> (Cinlar, probability and stochastic, p.389)
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} da e ^{p \cos a}= 2\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(p/2)^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$$

I am trying to understand this step. $e^{p \cos a} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(p \cos a)^k}{k!}$. Using this,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{p^k}{k!}\int_0^{2\pi} da \cos^k a.$$
$\cos^k a = (1/2)^k (e^{i a} + e^{-ia})^k = (1/2)^k \sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} e^{iak}e^{-2iaj}$. Using this,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(p/2)^k}{k!}\int_0^{2\pi} da \sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} e^{iak}e^{-2iaj}.$$
I am stuck here. I don't know if this is the right approach. Can you give some help?

Comment: For an integer $n\,\,\int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}dx=2\pi$ only at $n=0$; otherwise - zero